# How do I access the command prompt in Lubuntu?

Tags: command-line, prompt

I have managed the task of loading Lubuntu into a partition of my ThinkPad T41, and am so far very happy with it.  I have learned that there is a driver available for my old scanner, but apparently it has to be loaded by typing into command prompt.  I'm sure other programs will require the same.  I had not found how to access the command prompt from my desktop.  But now I know!  Where is it?  Click the "start" button on the bottom left, then click on "Run" and it comes up.  DUH!

Comment: what about ctrl+alt+t ?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-T is definitely the best way to go about this. I'm not sure about the Lubuntu menu specifically, but it should be in there (probably called Terminal). However, the Ctrl+Alt+T keystroke is very handy. I disagree with @chapolo's answer because that locks you into to *only* a terminal with no GUI. The only time I've ever had a use for a VT is when installing NVIDIA graphics (requires X not be running) or shutting down a locked up X session. (Hint: If you use his method, use Alt+F7 to get back to the graphic desktop)

Comment: I found that the Ctrl+Alt+T works and is convenient, and I can remember it.  Apparently command prompt is a different place than "Run" although that seems to be a command prompt operation as well.  The command prompt window is obviously required for changes of programming, such as loading drivers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From [**UsingTheTerminal**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal):

> ## In LXDE (Lubuntu)
>
> **Menu** -> **Accessories** -> **LXTerminal**.
>
> **Keyboard Shortcut**: Ctrl + Alt + T

Answer (score 0):

You can try with :

- Alt+F2 and type lxterm
- Ctrl+Alt+T this is the default shortcut for both Lubuntu and Ubuntu
- from Menu -> Accessories -> LXTerminal

For some shortcuts to use with in lxterm see this [link](http://www.comfsm.fm/~dleeling/tech/lubuntu-lxde-openbox-desktop-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Comment: CAT is working here.  Alt+F2 doesn't.  I'm not French so the link doesn't help.  I'll stick with CAT (Ctrl+Alt+T)

Comment: Sorry about the old link. I just changed it